# Enable directory browsing for ASP.Net Development Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-development-serv

I want a directory listing/browsing available in my Asp.Net MVC application.
So I modified web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
</system.webServer>
```

and it works well under IIS or IIS Express.
But on VS Development Server it gives `HTTP 404 The resource cannot be found.`

Is there anything to make it work?

Comment: no luck. though, it's meant to tweak IIS Express, isn't it? under IIS Express everything already works ok